# Exporting Google Sheet to Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Objective: Export data from one sheet into a CSV created in Drive.

Currently the code is creating the spreadsheet with correct naming convention.

Issue: Data is not merging from the sheet into the created CSV.
The spreadsheet contains  1 cell with the word "undefined".

```js
function exportCSV() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.openById('REDACTED');
  var exportSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Export');
  var placementSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Placement Builder')
  var csvName = placementSheet.getRange('B12').getValue();
  var fileName = csvName + ".csv";
  var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName);
  var folderId = placementSheet.getRange('B11').getValue();
  DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(fileName, csvFile, MimeType.CSV);

  function convertRangeToCsvFile_(csvFileName) {
    var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Export').getActiveRange();
    try {
      var data = ws.getValues();
      Logger.log(ws);
      var csvFile = undefined;
      if (data.length > 1) {
        var csv = "";
        for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
          for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
            if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
              data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
            }
          }
          if (row < data.length - 1) {
            csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
          } else {
            csv += data[row];
          }
        }
        csvFile = csv;
      }
      return csvFile;
    } catch (err) {
      Logger.log(err);
      Browser.msgBox(err);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use activeRange here `function convertRangeToCsvFile_(csvFileName) {
    var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Export').getActiveRange();`? Don't you want the entire sheet? I would consider using getDataRange().

Comment: That worked. Thank you.